# Getting Selected values off Iframe

Tags: javascript

I have my dial page where i have dial with needle. Needle follows the cursor. On-click on the dial angle is given. The angle value is from js.query. I imported the dial page to my main page using iframes.I get dial image and angle within the frame but my question is how do i get the angle to appear somewhere else instead in my main page.
 This is how i imported my dial image on the main page.I would appreciate your help

```
<iframe name="clkwise1" id="clkwise1" src="Dial1.htm" width=150 height=215 frameborder=0 scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can use something like the following to access elements within the iframe.

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('#dial').data('angle');
```

You will want to change #iframe to the id of the iframe. You will also need to change #dial to the id of your dial element and make sure that when the dial is changed it updates an attribute on itself of data-angle to the value of the dial angle.

Comment: How would i do this in javascript??